# How to run CURL in the background of the page

Tags: php, curl

I am using following curl method to play audio clip but when I run it its taking me off from my current screen.

```
$pass = account_sid.':'.auth_token;
$url="$id.wav";
header("Content-Type: audio/x-wav");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

My question is that I already put the header false in curl then why its redirecting the URL?

Here I am trying to play audio file by click on a button and its working fine but by redirecting the existing URL. Is it possible to pause same click using CURL?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not in curl but is in some other JS/PHP code.  Even if curl returns header, when you echo them they becomes content not header, so the redirect should be caused by something else.

Comment: ok its on server side I have to use ajax to open the same. Thanks.